is it possible visualize weather conditions in HERE maps?
I want to visualize weather (precipitation, snow, etc.) via HERE maps like we do on google maps (see screenshot). Is it ever possible to do that in js (vue 3 if possible)?!
I see here maps has weather destination api which I can get only data in object.


Yes you can get "global precipitation image tile which can be overlaid on the map".
Refer to the documentation: https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/destination-weather-api-developer-guide/page/topics/example-precip-request.html

do you have any example? Docs seems a bit confusing
